# Lock config specs of a view (clearcase)

Tags: linux, clearcase

someone in the company occasionally change the config specs of a view that I use for running some commands through cronjob.

I wonder it there a way to lock the config specs or find out who changed it.

Answer (score 1):

If depends where is the view storage (which also contains the config spec).

You can see its path with a:

```
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro viewTag
```

Changing the config spec is done through a [`cleartool setcs`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm), which has no particular limitation.

So if the view storage path is a path only accessible by you (as an OS limitation, with ACL set to allow only you to access it, nothing to do with ClearCase), *then* only you will be able to change said config spec.